# Random Behavior in PWA install as a WebAPK

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, workbox, webapk

I create PWA app use reactjs and do/implement below steps for install it as a WebAPK (in android chrome):

1- valid manifest.json

2- install serviceworker

3- trusted https certificate

but when tap on add to home screen :

_most of the time install as a shortcut

_sometimes install app as a WebAPK and add to app list

my manifest.json like this :

```
{
  "short_name": "myApp",
  "name": "MyApp",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "digi_64.png",
      "sizes": "64x64",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "digi_192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "digi_256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "digi_512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "theme_color": "#009688",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF"
}
```

my service-worker.js like this :

```
   if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
        importScripts('https://*****.com/wb/workbox-sw.js');
        /* global workbox */
        if (workbox) {
            console.log('Workbox is loaded');
            workbox.setConfig({debug: true,});
            workbox.core.skipWaiting();
            workbox.core.clientsClaim();
    
    
            /* injection point for manifest2 files.  */
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([{"revision":"482c307b535cf7a7fbe9460442b55dca","url":"index.html"},{"revision":"98b6e856dfde863e1a6fe4805f1697e4","url":"precache-manifest.98b6e856dfde863e1a6fe4805f1697e4.js"},{"revision":"1f3e10ff760fbad3f46f5002dd79bd63","url":"static/css/2.3cacd7bc.chunk.css"},{"revision":"376ca0485936b424c1df510f151b2aa9","url":"static/css/main.1e1ff1ee.chunk.css"},{"revision":"f89239b5271cfa9ec33a13390bb4ffa1","url":"static/js/2.03724f23.chunk.js"},{"revision":"1ea92516068f62199d362ad2a1f3d0fa","url":"static/js/main.a8d04045.chunk.js"},{"revision":"175ae123e9bc4f88a4f3228075f328a7","url":"static/js/runtime-main.01ce8b7d.js"}]);

    
           
    
        } else {
            // console.log('Workbox could not be loaded SWA. No Offline support');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: when test url with lighthouse every things is green but give me one error : Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline